# Object query in Entity Framework 6.0

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6

```
private void AddProductsTabbedPanel()
    {
        using (ObjectContext context =
new ObjectContext("name=CoffeeShopDatabaseEntities"))
        {
            foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages)
            {
                ObjectQuery<TblProduct> filteredProduct = new ObjectQuery<TblProduct>("Select value P from TblProduct as P", context);

                foreach (TblProduct tpro in filteredProduct)
                {
                    Button btn = new Button();
                    btn.Text = tpro.Description;
                    tp.Controls.Add(btn);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

i am trying to add button on run time in control tab based on what is the content of TblProduct

But I got an error:

See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqJtv.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946663/could-not-be-resolved-in-the-current-scope-or-context-make-sure-that-all-refere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code Will Solve The Problem

```
private void AddProductsTabbedPanel()
    {
        string queryString = @"SELECT VALUE P FROM Tblproducts as P";

        foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages)
        {
            ObjectContext context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)cse).ObjectContext;
            ObjectQuery<TblProduct> filteredproduct = new ObjectQuery<TblProduct>(queryString, context);

            foreach (TblProduct tprod in filteredproduct)
            {
                Button b = new Button();
                b.Text = tprod.Description;
                tp.Controls.Add(b);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have TblProduct as a DbSet in the context.

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> TblProduct { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what type of "<Product>" object is i am getting error , sorry if i asked common question

Comment: @BilaHassan, Product is the name of your entity which you want to match TblProduct in your CoffeeShopDatabaseEntities